# Tidymodels: iterate over values of k values in nearest_neighbor()?

Tags: r, knn, tidymodels

I'm new to the Tidymodels framework and want to use nearest_neighbor() function across multiple K values e.g.

```
c(3,5,8,11),
```

but I don't know how to do that and at what stage of the whole process I should specify that (if it is at all possible).

I tried

```
nearest_neighbor(neighbors = c(3,5,8,11))
```

but neighbors must be a length 1 positive integer

Comment: Is your goal to tune the model? You should try `neighbors = tune()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the tuning functions built into tidymodels (take a look at the chapter in the [tidymodels book](https://www.tmwr.org/grid-search.html)). See the example below.

There is also the `usemodels` package, which will write out proper code for your specific data set.

example:

```r
library(tidymodels)
```

```r
tidymodels_prefer()
```

```r
knn_spec <- nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune()) %>% set_mode("regression")

set.seed(1)
sim_dat <- sim_regression(100)
sim_rs <- vfold_cv(sim_dat)

set.seed(2)
knn_res <- 
  knn_spec %>% 
  tune_grid(outcome ~ ., resamples = sim_rs, grid = tibble(neighbors = c(3, 5, 8, 11)))

show_best(knn_res, metric = "rmse")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>   neighbors .metric .estimator  mean     n std_err .config             
#>       <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1        11 rmse    standard    20.1    10    2.29 Preprocessor1_Model4
#> 2         8 rmse    standard    20.2    10    2.27 Preprocessor1_Model3
#> 3         5 rmse    standard    20.7    10    2.24 Preprocessor1_Model2
#> 4         3 rmse    standard    22.0    10    2.12 Preprocessor1_Model1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Oh wow, tidymodels seems to have an enormous amount of dedicated functions. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Yeah, they are _all_ listed here: https://www.tidymodels.org/find/

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map` to pass in a vector of values for `k`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

fitted_models <- c(3, 5, 8, 11) |> 
  map(\(k) nearest_neighbor(neighbors = k, mode = "regression") |> 
        fit(ridership ~ ., data = Chicago))
```

Example output

```
>fitted_models[[1]]
parsnip model object


Call:
kknn::train.kknn(formula = ridership ~ ., data = data, ks = min_rows(3,     data, 5))

Type of response variable: continuous
minimal mean absolute error: 1.943712
Minimal mean squared error: 13.00969
Best kernel: optimal
Best k: 3
```

Comment: That's not a very good solution. There is a lot of infrastructure for proper model tuning in tidymodels